# How to setup firebase authentication using Microsoft and certificate credentials

Tags: firebase-authentication

I have a working firebase project with microsoft authentication using **Client ID** and **Client Secret** as documented here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/microsoft-oauth

However, the Microsoft documentation discourages the use of client secrets for production applications. The recommended way is using **certificate credentials** (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app#add-a-client-secret)

Is there any documentation out there on how to set this up or did anyone get this up an running? Very much appreciate any help!